# Is there a way to set the spin multiplicity in a VASP calculation?

Tags: vasp, spin

I will greatly appreciate if someone can point to whether I can specify the spin multiplicity of a vasp calculation?
I am trying to get the potential energy mapping of a system with neutral slab and a Na+ ion in the vacuum. My results has been a bit off compared to a lammps calculation, so I want to test the hypothesis of spin multiplicity definition in the VASP INCAR file.

Comment: I don't know much about VASP, but you can try the suggestions from [this blog](https://vaspcode.blogspot.com/2019/03/ispin-controls-spin-polarized-and-spin.html?m=1) and if it works you can add an answer here.

Comment: Thank you, this is extremely helpful!